# 256 bits Blowfish encryption in java

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

I am trying to encrypt data and send them to the server bye using 256 bits blowfish, but I do not know what is the proper provider for the key size. I have tried to change the CFB32 and CFB8 but does not work I have tried iv with 8 16 and 32 but it does not work. I have tried OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding also it did not work. 
and when I used blowfish/ECB/PKCS1Padding it gave me message that can not find any provider support blowfish/ECB/PKCS1Padding.

```
   // Create a Blowfish key
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");

    // Now set the keysize to 256 bits
    keyGenerator.init(256);

    Key key = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    System.out.println("Done generating the key.");

    // Create a cipher using that key to initialize it
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CFB8/NoPadding");


        //Cipher encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/C/NoPadding");
    System.out.println("good here");
     SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(iv);


  IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,spec);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get the "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size" when trying to use key size of 256, then you need to to download JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your JDK/JRE. The unlimited policy will allow you to use key sizes greater than the [predefined limits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#importlimits) (128 bits for blowfish).
The Oracle JDK 7 unlimited JCE policy can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html), make sure to read the readme.txt included in the archive and follow the instuctions.

If you get the "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be ??? bytes long" then you have a mismatch between the actual IV array length and the IV length expected by the mode and padding specified in the Cipher.getInstance() argument. For "Blowfish/CFB8/NoPadding" the IV should be 8 bytes long, but in your code you create a 16-bytes long IV array.

If you have some other problems then you should really update your question and specify what the actual problem is and what the actual exception (preferably with the stacktrace) is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is useful and really helpful my code works fine after I downloaded The Oracle JDK 7 unlimited JCE policy. and about the IV yes it is 8. infact before I had tried 8 and 16 and 32 because I did not know exactly what is the problem. And now it became clear the problem was the the JCE after downloading it, every thing works fine. thanks once again.

Comment: @user3397765 Now accept Oleg's answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For 256 bit Keysize, need to add JCE jar in project and referred code will work for that.

JCE Jar : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

BlowfishUtility: https://github.com/NikhilPareek88/BlowfishUtility